# Can't make Gtk.TextView () fill whole parent Gtk.Box

Tags: gtk, vala

Can't make `Gtk.TextView ()` hexpand. Only expands to like 2/3 of parent and wraps words too early.

Source: https://github.com/stsdc/monitor/blob/d3685a314712e263987da942724432c3469108e6/src/Widgets/ProcessView/ProcessInfoView.vala#L52-L61

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lovely application you built here, I particularly like the native indicator!

Looking into your Application.css:

```
.command_wrapper {  
    background-color: #fdf6e3;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);  
    padding: 5px;  
    padding-right: 190px; 
}
```

In ProcessInfoView.vala (58:59), you are applying the 'command_wrapper' class to the command_wrapper Box widget:

```
var command_wrapper = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
command_wrapper.get_style_context ().add_class ("command_wrapper");
```

[image]

Commenting the `padding-right: 190px` line will result in the TextBox 'expanding' horizontally:

[image]

Also, I believe it is worth mentioning that in dark mode, the text in the TextBox is unreadable:

[image]

Comment: stupid mistake. Thank You. I will definitely add a dark style.
Also do You maybe know how to fix glitches when resizing the pane?